# Perl - How do I sort an array of arrays based on the value of a column while maintaining the order specified in a hash?

Tags: perl, sorting

%probes - is a list of probe names in an arbitrary order (organized by their location, not alpabetically nor numerically).

I need to sort an array of arrays (@data_a) based on the value of a the first column/cell in each array (the probe name) but sort them based on the order I specified in the ordered hash %probes.

@data_a looks like:

```
(
 (D88 5833.4 82544.0),
 (D92 3431.1 3432.1),
 ....
)


@data_asort=sort {$a->[0] cmp $b->[0]} @data_a;
```

Will sort by a specific column, and this works, but sorts alphanumerically:

```
(
 (100X 45454.1 48482.2),
 (105Y 49911.1 81819.2),
...
)
```

I see that:

```
@data_bsort=sort {$probes{$b} <=> $probes{$a}} keys %probes;
```

Will sort a list of names based on the order in %probes.

I need to combine these two somehow, to sort the large array by the first column (probe name) maintaining all the numerical values associated, sorted in the order of %probes.

The order I want specified in the %probes hash:

```
my %probes = ("KCNT2 E3"=>1,"KCNT2 E1"=>2,"CFH E1"=>3,...);
```

The combined method suggested below:

```
@data_bsort= sort {$probes{$a->[0]} <=> $probes{$b->[0]} } @data_a;
```

Does not affect the order of the arrays, but this may be because it was meant to sort an array and not an array of arrays.

Comment: So `'D88'` and `'D92'` are keys in `%probes`?

Comment: Yes they are, and are the first two in the pre-sorted order.  KCNT2 E3 should come first.

Comment: Miller offers an answer, but when his is not chosen he puts the question on hold.  Makes perfect sense surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe based on what you wrote this is what you want:

```
@data_sort = sort {$probes{$a->[0]} <=> $probes{$b->[0]} } @data_a
```

That sorts the array refs in @data_a based on each array ref's first value being used as a key in the %probes hash.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information in your question to give you a suggestion besides the obvious:

```
my @data_sort = sort {$probes{$a->[0]} <=> $probes{$b->[0]} } @data_a;
```

However, I have two pointers that will likely go a long way to assisting you in solving the problem yourself.

1. Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY perl script.

   This is the #1 thing that you can do to be a better programmer, and is something that one should model every time they're asking a question on SO.

   There will be an initial barrier to entry of having to rework your script with `my` declarations before each of your variables, but this is a worthwhile case.   Also, don't be tempted to be lazy and just declare all your variables at the top of a script.  Try to give each variable the smallest scope possible.  This not only makes ones code more readable, but it also helps these two pragmas point out obvious bugs to you.

   In this case, it's very possible that you're using keys or values that are actually undefined, and it would really help if `warnings` was there to help you like with the following message:

   ```
   Use of uninitialized value in sort
   ```
2. When sorting by a complicated structure, considering using a `map` or a `for` to print out the transformation first.

   ```
   # my @data_sort = sort {$probes{$a->[0]} <=> $probes{$b->[0]} } @data_a;

   print "'$probes{$_->[0]}'\n" for @data_a;
   ```

   You've stated in you revised question that the above `sort` didn't work?  Well, in order to debug it would be useful to see what you're actually sorted by.

Anyway, you're in the right place to get help with your problem, but you just need to provide more information before you're going to get detailed help.

See if you can scale down your problem to a short example data structure of say 5 elements.  To the same thing with your `%probes` structure and share those along with a detail of what your expected sort order would be.